# GNU Make (running program on multiple files)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to run a program, on a set of files, using GNU Make:

I have a variable that loads some filenames alike this:

```
FILES=$(shell ls *.pdf)
```

Now I'm wanting to run a program 'p' on each of the files in 'FILES', however I can't seem to figure how to do exactly that.

An example of the 'FILES' variable would be:

```
"a.pdf k.pdf omg.pdf"
```

I've tried the $(foreach,,) without any luck, and #!bin/bash like loops seem to fail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write loop in makefile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490949/how-to-write-loop-in-makefile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a shell loop within the command:

```
all:
    for x in $(FILES) ; do \                                                
      p $$x ; \
    done
```

(Note that only the first line of the command must start with a tab, the others can have any old whitespace.)

Here's a more Make-style approach:

```
TARGETS = $(FILES:=_target)

all: $(TARGETS)
    @echo done

.PHONY: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): %_target : %
    p $*
```

Comment: perfect, I went with the first one, that's the more readable to me.