# Multi-line bash commands in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

Considering that every command is run in its own shell, what is the best way to run a multi-line bash command in a makefile? For example, like this:

```
for i in `find`
do
    all="$all $i"
done
gcc $all
```

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You can use backslash for line continuation. However note that the shell receives the whole command concatenated into a single line, so you also need to terminate some of the lines with a semicolon:

```
foo:
    for i in `find`;     \
    do                   \
        all="$$all $$i"; \
    done;                \
    gcc $$all
```

But if you just want to take the whole list returned by the `find` invocation and pass it to `gcc`, you actually don't necessarily need a multiline command:

```
foo:
    gcc `find`
```

Or, using a more shell-conventional `$(command)` approach (notice the `$` escaping though):

```
foo:
    gcc $$(find)
```

Comment: Yes, a short answer 1. $ := $$ 2. append multiline with \ BTW bash guys usually recommend to replace \`find\` call with $$(find)

Answer (score 143):

As indicated in the question, **every sub-command is run in its own shell**.  This makes writing non-trivial shell scripts a little bit messy -- *but it is possible!*  The solution is to consolidate your script into what make will consider a single sub-command (a single line).

### Tips for writing shell scripts within makefiles:

1. Escape the script's use of `$` by replacing with `$$`
2. Convert the script to work as a single line by inserting `;` between commands
3. If you want to write the script on multiple lines, escape end-of-line with `\`
4. Optionally start with `set -e` to match make's provision to abort on sub-command failure. You can also use `set -e -o pipefail` to make sure errors in pipe commands cause the script to abort (note: this is a bashism, so requires `SHELL := /bin/bash` or similar)
5. This is totally optional, but you could bracket the script with `()` or `{}` to emphasize the cohesiveness of a multiple line sequence -- that this is not a typical makefile command sequence

Here's an example inspired by the OP:

```
mytarget:
    { \
    set -e ;\
    msg="header:" ;\
    for i in $$(seq 1 3) ; do msg="$$msg pre_$${i}_post" ; done ;\
    msg="$$msg :footer" ;\
    echo msg=$$msg ;\
    }
```

Comment: You may also want [`SHELL := /bin/bash`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets) in your makefile to enable BASH-specific features such as [process substitution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe).

Comment: Subtle point: The space after `{` is crucial to prevent interpretation of `{set` as an unknown command.

Comment: Subtle point #2: In the makefile it probably doesn't matter, but the distinction between wrapping with `{}` and `()` makes a big difference if you sometimes want to copy the script and run it directly from a shell prompt.  You can wreak havoc on your shell instance by declaring variables, and especially modifying state with `set`, inside of `{}`.  `()` prevents the script from modifying your environment, which is probably preferred.  Example (**this will end your shell session**): `{ set -e ; } ; false`.

Comment: You can include comments by using the following form: `command ; ## my comment \\` (the comment is between `;` and `\\`).  This seems to work fine except that *if* you run the command manually (by copy-and-paste), the command history will include the comment in a way that breaks the command (if you try to reuse it).  [Note: The syntax highlighting is broken for this comment due to the use of backslash inside backtick.]

Comment: If you want to break a string in bash/perl/script inside makefile, close the string quote, backslash, newline, (no indentation) open string quote. Example; perl -e  QUOTE print 1; QUOTE BACKSLASH NEWLINE  QUOTE print 2 QUOTE

Comment: I just found that I needed to wrap compound statements with parentheses, for reasons that I can't explain at the moment:  `( false && true )`.  Without the parentheses, this isn't stopping the script.

Comment: ... the preceding note about parentheses may only be relevant on some (buggy?) platforms.

Comment: @nobar: in a Makefile, is whitespace-backslash-newline-whitespace replaced by a space or by an empty string?

Comment: @glennjackman, In the typical case, that would be interpreted as white-space.  I don't see the case where it would be considered a string (perhaps if it was somehow quoted).   In my example, I generally include a semicolon in that sequence -- so it's just used to separate commands.

Comment: Sometimes, you may want to use `&` instead of `;` as the command separator (puts the command in the background).

Answer (score 27):

The ONESHELL directive allows to write multiple line recipes to be executed in the same shell invocation.

```
all: foo

SOURCE_FILES = $(shell find . -name '*.c')

.ONESHELL:
foo: ${SOURCE_FILES}
    FILES=()
    for F in $^; do
        FILES+=($${F})
    done
    gcc "$${FILES[@]}" -o $@
```

There is a drawback though : special prefix characters (‘@’, ‘-’, and ‘+’) are interpreted differently.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html

Comment: perfect, why is this not at the top!

Answer (score 3):

Of course, the proper way to write a Makefile is to actually document which targets depend on which sources.  In the trivial case, the proposed solution will make `foo` depend on itself, but of course, `make` is smart enough to drop a circular dependency.  But if you add a temporary file to your directory, it will "magically" become part of the dependency chain.  Better to create an explicit list of dependencies once and for all, perhaps via a script.

GNU make knows how to run `gcc` to produce an executable out of a set of `.c` and `.h` files, so maybe all you really need amounts to

```
foo: $(wildcard *.h) $(wildcard *.c)
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just invoking the commands?

```
foo:
       echo line1
       echo line2
       ....
```

And for your second question, you need to escape the `$` by using `$$` instead, i.e. `bash -c '... echo $$a ...'`.

EDIT: Your example could be rewritten to a single line script like this:

```
gcc $(for i in `find`; do echo $i; done)
```

Comment: Cause "every command is run in its own shell", while I'm need to use result of command1 in command2. Like in example.

Comment: If you need to propagate information between shell invocations you need to use some form of external storage, such as a temporary file. But you can always rewrite your code to execute multiple commands in the same shell.

Comment: +1, especially for the simplified version. And isn't it the same as doing just ``gcc `find```?

Comment: Yes, it is. But you could of course do more complex things than just 'echo'.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post while looking up how to detect if docker is running from a Makefile...didnt find an example so I wrote one. Here is the GNUmakefile in context...

https://github.com/RandyMcMillan/make-docker-start

```
OS                                      :=$(shell uname -s)
export OS
```

---

```
.ONESHELL:
docker-start:##     detect whether docker is running...
    @( \
        while ! docker system info > /dev/null 2>&1; do\
        echo 'Waiting for docker to start...';\
        if [[ '$(OS)' == 'Linux' ]]; then\
         systemctl restart docker.service;\
        fi;\
        if [[ '$(OS)' == 'Darwin' ]]; then\
         open --background -a /./Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker;\
        fi;\
    sleep 1;\
    done\
    )
docker-pull:docker-start##  pull alpine image
    docker pull alpine
```