# Interpreting python program line by line from makefile

Tags: python, bash, makefile

I need to interpret a python program line by line. I am using -c option to python and have makefile like this.

```
all:   
python -c  
"print 'aa'  
   print 'bb'"
```

When I run it with make I get

```
python -c "print 'aa'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

when I take out the same python lines and run from bash, it works fine. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Makefile truly is

```
all:   
python -c  
"print 'aa'  
   print 'bb'"
```

I would expect to see more errors.  With that makefile, make will first attempt to run `python -c`, which should generate errors like:`Argument expected for the -c option`.  It will then abort and not even try to run the shell command `"print 'aa'`.  You need line continuations and semi-colons.

```
all:   
        python -c   \
        "print 'aa';   \
        print 'bb'"
```

The semi-colon is necessary because make strips all the newlines and passes the string `python -c "print 'aa'; print bb'"` to the shell (whatever SHELL is set to).

Answer (score 1):

Every line of a make rule is executed in a different shell instance. You need to escape the newlines (with `\`) or put it all on one line.

Also the makefile snippet as given should be giving you an error about unexpected arguments to `-c`. Your error indicates that your snippet is actually:

```
all:   
python -c "print 'aa'  
   print 'bb'"
```

Not that that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question. I think your problem is that your program is spanning multiple lines, but your makefile isn't interpreting it that way. Adding slashes should clear that up.

[Multiline bash commands in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121182/multiline-bash-commands-in-makefile)