# multiple line bash script and concatenation of evaluated bash variables in make file directive

Tags: linux, bash, gcc, makefile

Previously I had a directive `pictDBM` that was something like this:

```
    all: pictDBM

    pictDBM : db_list.o db_delete.o db_utils.o error.o pictDBM.o 
          db_create.o dedup.o image_content.o pictDBM_tools.o db_read.o
                      gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

This part worked very well.

Then I thought I wanted to be able to add an optional argument given from the command line. This option would then go into the `gcc` command line that I execute in the `pictDBM` subpart.

I approched the problem by using a `OPTS=""` variable that I declare in my code(at the beginning of the makefile before any directive). My aim is to call make like this:
`make all OPT='-g'`.

Then I declared a variable `base=gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)`

Part of my solution was to use a if else construct to include or not my option variable `${OPT}` to the `${base}` `gcc` command that I execute in pictDBM.

I red [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121182/multiline-bash-commands-in-makefile), that helped build my multi-line if else construct:

```
pictDBM : db_list.o db_delete.o db_utils.o error.o pictDBM.o 
    db_create.o dedup.o image_content.o pictDBM_tools.o db_read.o
        if [ ! -z "$$OPT" ];    \
        then    \
                echo "$$base $$OPT" ; \ #for debugging purposes
                eval "$$base $$OPT"  ;   \
        else    \
                eval "$$base" ;  \
        fi ;
```

When I simply execute `make all` everything seems to be ok with make, and the output program works well.

but when I execute `make all OPTS='-g'` I get the following output:

```
 -g
/bin/sh: 1: eval: -g: not found
makefile:16: recipe for target 'pictDBM' failed
make: *** [pictDBM] Error 127
```

you can see echo prints only -g, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the conditional or `eval`, just specify `CFLAGS` directly on the command line:

```
make all CFLAGS=-g
```

and override the variable in the makefile:

```
override CFLAGS += # Your local options

all: pictDBM

pictDBM: db_list.o db_delete.o db_utils.o error.o pictDBM.o \
          db_create.o dedup.o image_content.o pictDBM_tools.o db_read.o
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

`CFLAGS` is kind of odd here however, you shouldn' t be passing compilation flags during linking.

Linking options can be specified with `LDFLAGS`; since `pictDBM` has `pictDBM.o` as a prerequisite, and you're already using `LDLIBS` correctly, you can rely on make's implicit linking rule, no recipe needed.

```
override LDFLAGS += # Your local options

pictDBM: db_list.o db_delete.o db_utils.o error.o pictDBM.o \
          db_create.o dedup.o image_content.o pictDBM_tools.o db_read.o
```

---

RE your comment, you need to specify `override` on the very first definition of a variable, otherwise it won't work:

```
override CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config vips --cflags) -std=c99 -Wall
override LDLIBS += $(shell pkg-config vips --libs) -lm -lssl -lcrypto

pictDBM: db_list.o db_delete.o db_utils.o error.o pictDBM.o db_create.o dedup.o image_content.o pictDBM_tools.o db_read.o
```

Comment: I've done what you advise to do my make file now looks like this:
`CFLAGS += -std=c99 -Wall`  <br/>
`CFLAGS += $$(pkg-config vips --cflags)`  <br/>
`LDLIBS += $$(pkg-config vips --libs) -lm -lssl -lcrypto`  <br/>
`override CFLAGS+=`  <br/>
`override LDFLAGS+=`  <br/>

`all : pictDBM`  <br/>

`pictDBM : db_list.o db_delete.o db_utils.o error.o pictDBM.o   db_create.o` <br/>
`dedup.o image_content.o pictDBM_tools.o db_read.o`<br/>

but when I do `make all CFLAGS=-g`<br/>
I get:

Comment: `cc -g    -c -o pictDBM.o pictDBM.c
In file included from pictDB.h:32:0,
                 from pictDBM.c:11:
/usr/local/include/vips/vips.h:85:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'pictDBM.o' failed
make: *** [pictDBM.o] Error 1`
What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry the formatting is terrible.I tried to do the maximum for putting linebreaks. But through trial and failure it ended up looking like this :(