# Bash 'until' loop syntax error in Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, syntax-error, gnu-make

Trying to check whether or not a database is ready by it's HTTP status before executing the load_db script:

```
db:
    ## Startup database container, takes about 30 seconds to be available on port 7474

load_db: db
    ## Check status and break loop if successful
    until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:7474) ; do \
        printf '.' ; \
        sleep 5 ; \
    done
    ## load database
```

Everytime I run `make load_db` I keep getting the error: 
`` /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;' ``

Comment: Inside the Makefile, you'll need to escape the '$' in order for it to reach the shell interpreter.  '$' becomes '$$': https://stackoverflow.com/a/29085684/86967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'Makefile' the '$(something)' has special meaning - it will result to Make's variable something (or environment variable with the same name). You want to escape the '$', so that it will get passed to the shell. Usually, just using '$$' will do the trick.

```
load_db: db
    ## Check status and break loop if successful
    until $$(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:7474) ; do \
        printf '.' ; \
        sleep 5 ; \
    done
```

Comment: This ended up being the perfect solution.