# How the get the length of a vector in a makefile and use it in a for loop?

Tags: bash, makefile

How can I get the dimension of a vector in a makefile? I want to have a simple loop that goes through each element of 2 same-sized vectors.

Example that doesn't work in terms of loop nor size of vectors but to give you an idea of what I am thinking about. The loop notation was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490949/how-to-write-loop-in-makefile):

```
V1=one two three four
V2=bird stones parks bears
print:
     size={#$(V1)}      <- this is my invented notation, obviously it doesn't work.
     i=0
     while [[ $$i -le $$size ]] ; do \ 
    echo $(V1)[i] $(V2)[i] ; \
    ((i = i + 1)) ; \
done
```

Output:

```
one bird
two stones
three parks
four bears
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this structure is a good fit for a Makefile. I think it would be best to put all the loop inside a perl script and just call the perl script from the Makefile. That said, here's how I would write this if I had to write it in an all make + linux way :

```
V=one:bird two:stones three:parks four:bears
print:
    @for vv in $(V) ; do echo $${vv} | sed 's/:/ /' ; done
```

which generates

```
one bird
two stones
three parks
four bears
```

Also AFAIK, a line like `V1=one two three four` does not create a `vector`. It creates the string `"one two three four"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
# idea from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1491012/493161
V1 ?= one two three four
V2 ?= bird stones parks bears
COUNT := $(words $(V1))
SEQUENCE := $(shell seq 1 $(COUNT))
print:
    $(foreach number, $(SEQUENCE), \
     echo $(word $(number), $(V1)) $(word $(number), $(V2));)
```

in action:

```
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ make -s -f answer.mk 
one bird
two stones
three parks
four bears
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant without loop:

```
V1=one two three four
V2=bird stones parks bears
print:
    @echo $(subst -, ,$(join $(V1),$(addprefix -,$(addsuffix :,$(V2))))) | sed 's/:\( \)*/\n/g'
```