# What is the meaning of a double dollar sign in bash/Makefile?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

When inserting a shell script inside a Makefile we have (?) to use a double dollar sign ($$) to make reference to variables. Why is that so?

```
for number in 1 2 3 4 ; do \
    echo $$number ; \
done
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As per [gnu make official doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html):

> Variable and function references in recipes have identical syntax and
>   semantics to references elsewhere in the makefile. They also have the
>   same quoting rules: if you want a dollar sign to appear in your
>   recipe, you must double it (‘$$’). For shells like the default shell,
>   that use dollar signs to introduce variables, it’s important to keep
>   clear in your mind whether the variable you want to reference is a
>   make variable (use a single dollar sign) or a shell variable (use two
>   dollar signs).

So in short:

- makefile variable => use a single dollar sign
- shell variable => use two dollar signs

Comment: To elaborate on the [syntax for variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html): "*To substitute a variable’s value, write a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable in parentheses or braces: either `$(foo)` or `${foo}` is a valid reference to the variable `foo`. This special significance of `$` is why you must write `$$` to have the effect of a single dollar sign in a file name or recipe.*"

Answer (score 14):

`$$` is the **PID**(process ID) of your current process.

```
$ ps -ef|grep $$
user       208465  200620  0 10:30 pts/4    00:00:00 bash

$ for number in 1 2 3 4 ; do \
    echo $$number ; \
done
208465number
208465number
208465number
208465number
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is specifically about a shell script in a Makefile.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly applicable to this example -- except if the code shown is executed via `$(shell ...)` instead of being a rule:

With secondary expansion enabled, make might also interpret the double dollar itself in the second processing phase, when it occurrs in the prequisites list. (First phase: read file, set variables; second phase: find and invoke dependency targets, execute rules)

This is used to allow dynamically specifying dependency targets, when the variable with the targets name is only available later in the file.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html.