# How to kill process by awk?

Tags: bash

In my makefile I have a command

```
kill `ps aux | awk '/process_name/' | awk '$11 ~ /special_mask/ {print $2}'`
```

It works through the terminal but when I try to call it through the command `make my-command` it returns

```
kill `ps aux | awk '/process_name/' | awk '1 ~ /special_mask/ {print }'`
```

and it can't execute `kill` without process id.
How could I fix it?

Comment: You can use: `ps aux | awk '/[p]rocess_name/ && $11 ~ /special_mask/{print $2}' | xargs kill`

Comment: @anubhava it doesn't help. maybe there is a way to check that select returns not empty string?

Comment: @Jens: Use the `-r` flag in `xargs` (`GNU` specific not in `POSIX`) which means only if the commands before the pipeline produce an output string (stdout) the command _after_ `xargs` is run (`kill` in your case).  `.. | xargs -r kill`. This way if the process is not found, no errors are seen on the console (the command `kill` is not run)

Comment: @Inian Thank you for your response. There is no error with -r, but command still returns ...&& 1 ~ /php/{print }'... It looses $11 and $2.

Comment: Remember 1 is not the same as $1 in Awk

Comment: @anubhava Yes I am

Comment: @anubhava In my Makefile I have got next strings `my-command:
 ps aux | awk '/[s]ocket-ws.php/ && $11 ~ /php/{print $2}' | xargs -r kill`. So I could call this comand using `make my-command`

Comment: Oh Makefile needs double `$$`, Use: `ps aux | awk '/[p]rocess_name/ && $$11 ~ /special_mask/{print $$2}' | xargs -r kill`

Comment: @anubhava Wow, never knew about it. Thank you so much. Write it as an answer and I will confirm it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Makefile needs double `$$` for shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26564874/548225).

You can use:

```
ps aux | awk '/[p]rocess_name/ && $$11 ~ /special_mask/{print $$2}' | xargs -r kill
```