# Making 'make clean' ask for confirmation

Tags: makefile, cmake

Is there a way to make the command `make clean` require user confirmation? I mistakenly executed it and now I have to wait 6 hours for the build to complete again.

The `Makefile`s were created by `cmake`.

Desired workflow:

```
> make clean
> [make] Are you sure you want to remove all the built files? [Y/N]
> N
> [make] Target 'make clean' not executed.

> make clean
> [make] Are you sure you want to remove all the built files? [Y/N]
> Y
> [make] Target 'make clean' executed.
```

Comment: CMake doesn't have an option for such "prompt" on `make clean`. And I know no way for attach additional actions for *clean* target. (The only way to affect on `make clean` behavior is adding files to [ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_dir/ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES.html)). You may create another target (say, `make remove`), in which call some sort of "prompt" and then `make clean`.

Answer (score 62):

I'm not familiar with cmake, but for gnu make, one possible hack would be:

```
clean: check_clean

check_clean:
    @echo -n "Are you sure? [y/N] " && read ans && [ $${ans:-N} = y ]

.PHONY: clean check_clean
```

If `check_clean` fails (user does not type in `y`), then make will exit with an error before performing the clean.

Comment: Using the check as a prerequisite is clever.  There's probably also a variant that could use the same check in the `clean` rule recipe via a lot more BASH scripting.  That might let you make clean optional while still building other targets.  Since the OP is using cmake, he may require cross-platform...so BASH may be dodgy.  Maybe some equivalent using python?

Comment: Little improvement:
``@echo -n "Are you sure? [y/N] " && read ans && [ $${ans:-N} == y ]``

Comment: I am using case: `@( read -p "Are you sure?!? [y/N]: " sure && case "$$sure" in [yY]) true;; *) false;; esac )`

Comment: @HardcoreHenry: are you sure it is `[ $${ans:-N} == y ]` and not `[ $${ans:-N} = y ]`? When using your command, my Makefile fails when typing anything, but when I change to the single equal character, I works well.

Comment: Both work for me, but I just looked it up, and apparently `==` is not Posix compliant so may not work on some shells.   I'll update the answer to use a single `=`.   Thanks.

Comment: Why does it display `-n` before `Are you sure? [y/N]` on macOS terminal? It doesn't do so on linux terminal somehow.

Comment: @stt106 -- I don't have a mac, but I suspect that what you're seeing is a cut and paste error with the dash --  check that the dash in the `-n` is a regular dash as opposed to an em dash

Comment: @HardcoreHenry, why are there two `$$`: `$${ans:-N}`?

Comment: @HardcoreHenry, I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26564874/4223982.

Answer (score 2):

Makefile:

```
clean:
    @read -p "Are you sure? [y/N] " ans && ans=$${ans:-N} ; \
    if [ $${ans} = y ] || [ $${ans} = Y ]; then \
        printf $(_SUCCESS) "YES" ; \
    else \
        printf $(_DANGER) "NO" ; \
    fi
    @echo 'Next steps...'



_SUCCESS := "\033[32m[%s]\033[0m %s\n" # Green text for "printf"
_DANGER := "\033[31m[%s]\033[0m %s\n" # Red text for "printf"
```

Comment: We can use `exit 1` to error out if next statement need not to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
clean:
    @echo -n "Are you sure? [Y/n] " && read ans && [ $${ans:-Y} != Y ] && echo "Aborted" && exit 1
    ... Rest of code here
```

Comment: Downvoted since there is a bug, and a comment on HardcoreHenry's answer would have suited better, also short and sloppy answer..