# Command not running inside string interpolation for Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to dynamically fill in variables for some commands I have inside my Makefile. However, I'm not sure why the commands turn into an empty string instead of running it inside the string.

Example:

```
test:
    echo "hello $(cat foo.txt)"
```

Output:

```
$ make test
echo "hello "
hello
```

Preferred Output:

```
$ make test
echo "hello (contents of foo.txt)"
hello (contents of foo.txt)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 2 dollars:

```
test:
    echo "hello $$(cat foo.txt)"
```

See [What is the meaning of a double dollar sign in
bash/Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26564874/3691891)

And notice that you can add `@` to prevent make from printing what's it
going to do and that you don't have to specify `test` target
specifically because the first one will always be run:

```
test:
    @echo "hello $$(cat foo.txt)"
```

Run:

```
$ make
hello a b c
d e f
```