# How can I simplify this Makefile to make it less repetitive?

Tags: makefile

Make is one of those technologies where I go back and forth between whether or not I understand it.

This is certainly one instance where I know I must be doing something wrong, since Make was developed to make these tasks less repetitive.

```
all: 24.1 24.2 24.3

24.1:
    evm install emacs-24.1-bin || true
    emacs --version
    emacs --batch -L . -l ert -l test/tests.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit
24.2:
    evm install emacs-24.2-bin || true
    emacs --version
    emacs --batch -L . -l ert -l test/tests.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit
24.3:
    evm install emacs-24.3-bin || true
    emacs --version
    emacs --batch -L . -l ert -l test/tests.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit
```

How can I edit this Makefile to only lay out the test sequence once but be able to test against multiple versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
VERSIONS = 24.1 24.2 24.3

all :: $(VERSIONS)

$(VERSIONS) ::
    evm install emacs-$@-bin || true
    emacs --version
    emacs --batch -L . -l ert -l test/tests.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit
```

The `::` is a special kind of rule, that puts the target as phony (and has other properties, too).

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution, and allows me to have other targets in the Makefile, specifying this recipe for the `VERSIONS` *only*.  Good answer :) Do you have a link to the manual page which describes this use of `::`?

Comment: Here is a link in the GNU Make Manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon - but it's not GNU specific, it is "traditional" syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by _`::` stands for phony target_, but no way I read that statement makes it correct :-).  Double-colon rules don't create phony targets, although double-colon rules are often also declared phony (separately).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
all: 24.1 24.2 24.3

%:
        evm install emacs-$@-bin || true
        emacs --version
        emacs --batch -L . -l ert -l test/tests.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit
```

Comment: Excellent!  The manual page, for wanderers: [`Defining Last-Resort Default Rules`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Last-Resort.html).  Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry to take away the tick, but [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26827668/1443496) has a more precise definition.  This still worked in the meantime, though! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit that turning to ‘last resort’ strategies always makes me queasy: it feels as if going against the grain of the tool.  BSD make on the other hand allows explicit looping constructs, hence getting rid of the repetitive rules is straightforward:

```
VERSIONS = 24.1 24.2 24.3
all: ${VERSIONS}

.for VERSION in ${VERSIONS}
${VERSION}:
    evm install emacs-${VERSION}-bin || true
    emacs --version
    emacs --batch -L . -l ert -l test/tests.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit
.endfor
```

I’m well aware that this solution almost surely won’t help you at all; switching make implementation is almost certainly out of the question.  BSD make is sorely underrepresented though, so I thought it might be useful for other people to have an alternative approach documented.

As MadScientist correctly pointed out, GNU make doesn’t support any of the ‘dot constructs’ like `.for`, which are special to BSD make.  However, this question suggests a few other looping techniques that might be applicable to GNU make: **[How to write loop in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490949/how-to-write-loop-in-makefile)**

Comment: Oh, that's nifty :) GNU Make *may* support this (Emacs highlights the structure, but that doesn't mean anything), but it throws `Makefile:23: *** missing separator.  Stop.` at the `.for` line.

Comment: GNU make definitely does not support this syntax.  In fact none of the BSD "dot commands" (like `.for`) are available in GNU  make.

Comment: Yea, I get the missing seperator error also on GNU make.