# Static pattern rules with multiple %

Tags: makefile

Assume I have a code producing output depending on a single input variable, which I want to run for a range of input values. Following what is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12110773/1734710), I can do this with a makefile as follows:

```
out1 out2 out3: out%: a.out
    ./a.out $* > $@
```

Can this be generalized to more than one parameter? I.e. something like

```
out1_1 out1_2 out2_1 out2_2: out%_%: a.out
    ./a.out $*{1} $*{2} > $@
```

The `$*{i}` should refer to what the `i`th `%` matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, make only supports a single `%` in a target/prerequisite pattern.

To do what you want you would need to stem the entire `#_#` bit and then munge/parse that in shell.