# Using foreach loop in makefile with tcsh shell

Tags: makefile, csh, tcsh

I'm trying to run:

```
SHELL   =/usr/bin/tcsh
foo: 
    @foreach i ( "a" "b" "c")\
    echo $$i\
    end
```

But I get this error

```
i: Undefined variable.
make: *** [foo] Error 1
```

I found this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490949/how-to-write-loop-in-makefile), but looks like it uses bash, not tcsh.

Comment: I don't know what that error is about exactly but I'm not sure you'll be able to get this to work regardless. I didn't think `tcsh` allowed loops all on one line and the line-continuation support in make doesn't keep the lines newline separated as far as I know. You might be able to use `.ONESHELL` in newer make versions to help here though.

Comment: make sure make  is really honoring your `SHELL = ...`? Just a target with `echo $$SHELL`? Good luck.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Thanks for teaching me using ONESHELL, but it didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you should not ever use `tcsh`, at least not for makefiles.  My personal opinion is that it's high time `csh` and all derivatives were relegated to the dustbin of history, for all purposes.  But they definitely [are not usable](http://www.ooblick.com/text/CshProgrammingConsideredHarmful.html) in makefiles.

From that link, note for example: *You can't combine multiline constructs in a csh using semicolons.*

In addition to the problems they have with single-line scripts, they won't work with make's parallel jobserver support because they do nasty things with file descriptors.

Comment: thanks and I agree with your arguments, but for this project I really have to make it work in tcsh.

Comment: You can downvote my answer if you want, but the fact remains it won't work.  See the link I posted.  csh syntax is not capable of writing complex commands on a single line: it REQUIRES newlines.  It also won't accept a complex commands containing newlines through the `-c` flag, for whatever reason, so ONESHELL doesn't work.  So, unless you're willing to compromise on one of your base requirements then you can't succeed.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, and I agree with your arguments about bash. It also seems to me that there is no direct way to do this. I just have to use tcsh, so as a workaround, I ended up calling a tcsh script that includes the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHELL = /usr/bin/tcsh
# but we can't use its loop constructs as they're multi-line

foo: 
    @sh -c 'for i in a b c; do echo $$i; done'
```

Comment: Interesting! But I have to run everything in tcsh without shortcuts to other shells.

Comment: Right, so I take it this is an exercise. I really think you'll need to use another language to do the iteration. You can pick any language you like but it can't be `tcsh`: its two built-in iteration constructs `foreach` and `while` both necessarily span multiple lines, while `make` converts all recipes to single lines.

Comment: Are you allowed to call `tcsh` itself? In that case I know a solution, but it's your exercise so I'll leave finding that up to you.