# Makefile - Execute a rule for every field in a variable

Tags: makefile

I have my project binary located at my repository's root, along with a Makefile used to build it.
This binary uses many of my self-made libraries, located in my `lib/` folder

For the purpose of building (and cleaning) my repository's binary, I want to implement the following execution :

*Instead of hardcoding the following lines,*

```
clean_binaries:
    make -C clean lib/folder1 -s
    make -C clean lib/folder2 -s
    make -C clean lib/another_folder -s
```

I created the `BIN_PATH` variable, containing the previous paths.

```
BIN_PATHS = lib/folder1 \
            lib/folder2 \
            lib/another_folder
```

And made a simple rule like this one :

```
clean_binaries: $(BIN_PATHS)
    make -C clean $< -s
```

**BUT** it only executes the line for the first field of the variable (`lib/folder1`), which is not what I want to do.

I thought about using implicit rules(?), just like I compile the .c files, but I couldn't get it right.
In the end, I simply wonder how to execute a rule for every *field* of a given variable, and this inside a Makefile, if there is any way to do so.

Thank you for your answers :]

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490949/how-to-write-loop-in-a-makefile

Comment: Oh well, out of all the things I checked I guess making a for loop wasn't one. Thank you for your answer, it should do the job !

Comment: start using non-recursive `makefiles`, have a look at https://github.com/igagis/prorab it is easy to use and have tutorials. Then you will not have to write any for-loops and lists of folders at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you get GNU make to generate a sequence of commands that vary by the
fields in a variable is to use the [foreach function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html), e.g.

**Makefile**

```
BIN_PATHS := lib/folder1 lib/folder2 lib/another_folder

.PHONY: clean_binaries

clean_binaries:
    $(foreach path,$(BIN_PATHS),make -C $(path) clean ;)
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
make -C lib/folder1 clean -s; make -C lib/folder2 clean -s; make -C lib/another_folder clean -s;
```

not requiring a shell-loop.

Note also that you need to correct:

```
make -C clean <directory>
```

to:

```
make -C <directory> clean
```