# How to properly write for loop in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I went through some posts, but still didn't get how it work.

My request is:

```
for i in *.json
do
  file = `echo $i |cut -d _ -f2`
  echo ${file}
  # do the rest tasks
done
```

How to convert above script to target of Makefile?

Here is what I tried

```
foo: 
    for i in *.json; do      \
       $(eval FILE = $(shell echo $$i |cut -d _ -f2));    \
       echo $(FILE) ;\
    done
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: How to write loop in a Makefile?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490949/how-to-write-loop-in-a-makefile

Comment: Thanks, I had gone through above url several times, but still can't make mine work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$(eval)` or `$(shell)` is ... not even wrong.

```
foo: 
    for i in *.json; do \
       file=$$(echo "$$i" |cut -d _ -f2); \
       echo "$$file"; \
    done
```

Notice the quoting of the filename variables, and the absence of spaces around the `=` assignment operator, and the doubling of any dollar sign in order to pass it through from `make` to the shell.

However, the shell provides a much better mechanism for this;

```
foo:
    for i in *.json; do \
        j=$${i#*_}; \
        echo "$${j%%_*}"; \
    done
```

or perhaps

```
foo:
    printf '%s\n' *.json \
    | sed 's/[^_]*_\([^_]*\)_.*/\1/'
```

If you only expect a single underscore, both of these can be further simplified.

Or maybe you are just looking for

```
makefile_variable := $(foreach x,$(wildcard *.json),$(word 2,$(subst _, ,$x)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why the output is different: `$${file}` and `$(file)`?

Comment: and how to use `makefile_variable` in target?

Comment: As already explained, a double dollar sign gets passed through to the shell, whereas a single dollar sign gets evaluated by `make` itself. To get `make` to interpolate the variable, simply reference it like any variable: `$(makefile_variable)`. If you need help, ask a new question (but please search and/or read some documentation first).