# gnumake: Execute each space-delimited word in recipe

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following Makefile.

```
.PHONY: run
run: bin/p1 bin/p2 bin/p3
    bin/p1
    bin/p2
    bin/p3

bin/%: %.cpp
    mkdir -p bin
    clang++ -o $@ $<
```

Is there a way to eliminate the repetition on the `run` rule? The prerequisites for `run` will continue to grow, so I would like to avoid specifying them twice. I'm trying to get something like this.

```
.PHONY: run
run: bin/p1 bin/p2 bin/p3
    $(foreach p,$^,$(shell $(p)))
```

However, this doesn't work and I'm actually not sure what this really does...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490949/how-to-write-loop-in-a-makefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a loop here. `make` calls it in a shell. `$$` is to make `i` as a shell variable

```
run: bin/p1 bin/p2 bin/p3
    for i in $^; do \
      $$i; \
    done
```

Comment: You should probably use `$$i || exit $$?` here, not just `$$i`, to ensure that the loop exits on the first failure.  That would make it the equivalent of the makefile in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this works.

```
.PHONY: run
run: bin/c1 bin/c2 bin/c3 bin/c4
    $(foreach c,$^,$(c) || exit 1;)

bin/%: %.cpp
    mkdir -p bin
    clang++ -std=c++17 -o $@ $<
```

The `foreach` ends up being replaced with this text.

```
bin/c1 || exit 1; bin/c2 || exit 1; bin/c3 || exit 1; bin/c4 || exit 1;
```

This gets sent to the shell as 1 long line.

Optionally, if you don't want to exit on the first failure, you can just have this.

```
$(foreach c,$^,$(c);)
```